# Why doesn't mypy pass when TypedDict calls update method

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Example:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class MyType(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: int

t = MyType(a=1, b=2)

t.update(b=3)
```

`mypy toy.py` complains

```
toy.py:9:1: error: Unexpected keyword argument "b" for "update" of "TypedDict"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: hmm... I haven't touched mypy before, but how does `t |= dict(b=3)` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears this is a known open issue for `mypy`: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6019

For now if you want `mypy` to not bother you with this error, you'll need to tell it to ignore it:

```py
t.update(b=3)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
```

Comment: Or (similarly in the meantime) supply a dict or tuple instead of a keyword, I suppose.

Comment: Indeed, `mypy` does not complain about `t.update({"b": 3})`